# Add fragment following Android Developer Documentation not working?

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-ktx

I recently found on https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/create, the way to create fragment as below, when we have `implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0"`

[image]

However, after following all the steps there, I still get an error on the `add` as shown below

[image]

I can easily fix it using

```
            supportFragmentManager.commit {
                setReorderingAllowed(true)
                add(R.id.container, MainFragment())
            }
```

But curious why is it not working? Did I miss anything?

Just to provide the context, my `imports` are as below

```
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import com.example.activityfragmentviewmodel.ui.main.MainFragment
import androidx.fragment.app.commit
```

And my library dependencies are

```
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.7.0'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.4.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.2'
    implementation "androidx.fragment:fragment-ktx:1.4.0"
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.4.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.4.0'
```

Comment: Did you select the 'Import' action in that exact dialog and import the [reified `add` extension method](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction).add(kotlin.Int,kotlin.String,android.os.Bundle))?

Comment: Thanks Ian. Looks like I just need to add `import androidx.fragment.app.add`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The reified `add` method that the documentation uses is an [extension method](https://developer.android.com/reference/kotlin/androidx/fragment/app/FragmentTransaction#(androidx.fragment.app.FragmentTransaction).add(kotlin.Int,kotlin.String,android.os.Bundle)), which means you need to import it, just like your `commit` extension method you've imported:

```
import androidx.fragment.app.add
```